# Incorrect test answers for an English test? (Urgent!)

Tags: who, test

I want to preface this and say that I am not a native English speaker. I'm planning to get into the university and to do it, I have to take a test to show how good my English is. And in this test several questions left me wondering why my answer got marked as incorrect. Here are these questions and the answer options:

Which of the two manuals is ... ? I think ... ; ... is not up to date.

1. the most useful ... the big one; the small
2. the most useful one ... the bigger; the smaller one (my answer)
3. the more useful ... the big one; the smaller
4. many more useful ... the biggest; the small

It’s incredible! I … to pay the rent.

1. ,who had no any income, will have
2. ,who have no income at all, will have
3. ,who has no income at all, will have (my answer)
4. have had no income at all than, that’s why I had

The first question is a bit weird and, frankly, I don't like any options here but I like the part "the smaller one is not up to date" in my answer because of the word "one". From my perspective, "the small(er) is not up to date" sounds clunky because "the small(er)" acts as a nominalized adjective but without "one" it seems like it's lacking something. Maybe I'm wrong.

The second one also caught me off-guard when I saw it. I guess the test creators expected me to answer ", who have no income..." but the third option sounded more natural to my ears. I have looked up online that there's a huge debate about it and more conservative English grammarians would probably put "have" here, not "has". But I just wonder if "has" can be considered more informal, but still correct English?

Any help with these questions is appreciated!

Comment: Because there are only two manuals, they wanted you to say "the more useful" rather than "the most useful". Native English speakers don't follow this rule—they use both *more* and *most* when there are just two things—but this is probably the rule they are expecting you to follow.

Comment: Interesting point, Peter. I didn't even consider that option. Wouldn't it be better to say "Which of the two manuals is more useful?", so without "the" at all?

Comment: *THE More* useful may fulfill some grammarian's wish but is not what one hears from an English speaker.*Yuch!* I believe your answer is just fine. One might say" *IS* more useful" but that would be it. I think the other question should get "who have no income at all". That is what I hear most. If these come out wrong please ask the teacher just who *He* has been listening to. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Elliot! Hopefully the teachers will be willing to hear me out. I'm glad that a native (?) English speaker agrees with me.

Comment: Update: my answer to the 2nd question got accepted, my answer to the 1st one didn't. Here are the comments (roughly translated to English): 1. The chosen option is incorrect because when choosing from 2 things, the usage of a superlative form in English is unacceptable. 2. The chosen variant is acceptable although is used very infrequently.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the reason that the correct answer is (3) is that this answer uses *more* and not *most*. According to some grammar authorities you are supposed to use comparatives (e.g., *more*) for two things, and superlatives (e.g., *most*) only for three or more things. See this [Grammar Girl column.](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/comparatives-versus-superlatives) The other differences between (2) and (3) are irrelevant; none of these differences makes the sentence incorrect.

However, the rule about not using superlatives for comparing two things is broken all the time by native English speakers; as the Grammar Girl column remarks, we say "put your best foot forward," even though nobody has more than two feet. So this rule is something you only need to worry about for English test questions.

For the second question, the correct answer is (2). The conjugation of the verb goes *I have*, so you need to say *I, who have*.

Comment: I think the "best foot forward" is expected to be read not so much as the better of the two feet you have, so much as "put your foot (either one) forward into the best position you can". I may be wrong, but that's the way I actually read it.

Comment: Thanks once again, Peter. I've learnt something today! I guess I'm more used to colloquial rather than literary English and it might play tricks on you when you do tests like that. I was also not aware of that have/has rule (or maybe I was but completely forgot about it). To my defence though (not that I need to defend myself, lol), in my native language I'd never use "have" in that instance. It would be ungrammatical. I guess English is a different language after all, eh.

Comment: @Prime Mover Have you checked etymology sources? None seems to suggest that 'best' hasn't always modified 'foot' here. It could be that using the correct 'better' here sounds weak, so people voted with their feet. As with 'That's one less problem.'

Comment: "I've put two of my hats on the table for you to choose from. One of them is my best hat."  ... "Which of the two hats is your best one?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: And it's also the case that "put your best foot forward" is not actually about feet, so you could argue that there are many more than two options, and "best" is grammatical.

Comment: That takes us into the scary realm of variability within idioms. And if plain English is nebulous, this gets Heisenbergic. Men-of-wars. Ships of the deserts. Cans of wormses.